# if statement with adding many picture in java swing

Tags: java, swing

Hi I'm working on a program that requires to a take a random number of dice 1-6

I want to show a picture for any number show .

Here I initialized the pictures with jlable

```
JLabel diceNumber;

Random r = new Random();
int roll;


ImageIcon dicePic1 = new ImageIcon("dice1_.png");
ImageIcon dicePic2 = new ImageIcon("dice2.png");
ImageIcon dicePic3 = new ImageIcon("dice3.png");
ImageIcon dicePic4 = new ImageIcon("dice4.png");
ImageIcon dicePic5 = new ImageIcon("dice5.png");
ImageIcon dicePic6 = new ImageIcon("dice6.png");

JLabel diceNum1 = new JLabel("", dicePic1, JLabel.CENTER);
JLabel diceNum2 = new JLabel("", dicePic2, JLabel.CENTER);
JLabel diceNum3 = new JLabel("", dicePic3, JLabel.CENTER);
JLabel diceNum4 = new JLabel("", dicePic4, JLabel.CENTER);
JLabel diceNum5 = new JLabel("", dicePic5, JLabel.CENTER);
JLabel diceNum6 = new JLabel("", dicePic6, JLabel.CENTER);
```

this is the panel where one picture will appear
with if statements and I have to initialize diceNumber

```
JPanel panel6 = new JPanel();
    diceNumber = new JLabel("1");

    if (diceNumber.getText().equals("1")) {
        panel6.add(diceNum1);
    }

    else if (diceNumber.getText().equals("2")) {
        panel6.add(diceNum2);
    }

    else if (diceNumber.getText().equals("3")) {
        panel6.add(diceNum3);
    }

    else if (diceNumber.getText().equals("4")) {
        panel6.add(diceNum4);
    }

    else if (diceNumber.getText().equals("5")) {
        panel6.add(diceNum5);
    }

    else if (diceNumber.getText().equals("6")) {
        panel6.add(diceNum6);
    }
```

here when I start rolling

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


    if (e.getSource() == dice) {

        roll = r.nextInt(6) + 1;

        if (roll == 1) {
            diceNumber.setText("1");
        }

        else if (roll == 2) {
            diceNumber.setText("2");
        }

        else if (roll == 3) {
            diceNumber.setText("3");
        }

        else if (roll == 4) {
            diceNumber.setText("4");
        }

        else if (roll == 5) {
            diceNumber.setText("5");
        }

        else if (roll == 6) {
            diceNumber.setText("6");
        }
```

the problem is thath diceNumber always takes the value "1" and never change
any help ?

Answer (score 3):

```
diceNumber = new JLabel("1");
```

immediately precedes the logical checks on the diceNumber text. At this stage, you have initiated a JLabel with the text "1", hence it will always be "1" at this stage. You don't change the text until much later, at which stage you no longer check to set the Dice image. The approach you have taken resembles a Rube Goldberg machine; triggering a series of events to perform a relatively simple task. A **simple** solution would be:

```
    List<JLabel> disc = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
        disc.add(new ImageIcon(String.format("dice%d_.png", i));
    }
```

Then when you need to change the image you call:

```
int roll = r.nextInt(6) + 1;
panel.add(disc[roll]);
```

Regardless, there are many improvements that can be made to the code as it is; I would recommend that you change the excessive amount of if statements to:

```
diceNumber.setText(roll.toString()); or
diceNumber.setText(roll + "");
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `actionPerformed()` method, you change the text of the `diceNumber` label, and that's all you're doing. You don't change the image displayed by the image label.

You should really really learn about arrays, and store your 6 images in an array. Your logic should be:

```
init() {
    // add a label displaying the number (1 by default)
    // add a label displaying the icon (1 by default)
}

actionPerformed() {
    // choose a random number
    // change the text of the number label
    // change the icon of the image label
}
```

And to do that, ni need for  big chain of if statements: it should just be

```
imageLabel.setIcon(images[randomRoll - 1]);
```